# Swift Combine share operator not working?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to share the output of a sequence. Why I don't have any values in the second subscription after I add the `share` operator?

```
import Combine

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

let test = [1,2,3].publisher.print().share()

test.sink { value in
    print("Go")
}.store(in: &cancellables)

test.sink { value in
    print("no go ?")
}.store(in: &cancellables)
```

The output is:

```
receive subscription: ([1, 2, 3])
request unlimited
receive value: (1)
Go
receive value: (2)
Go
receive value: (3)
Go
receive finished
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly because you used `share()` - it converts publisher into reference to shared publisher instance. So your first subscriber on attach requests everything available and publisher generates three events and completes (as it is actually once generating publisher). And your second subscriber is attached by reference to already finished shared publisher, so you seen nothing for it.

It is just chosen not very convenient publisher to investigate this operator.

The following should be helpful:

```
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    let source = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
    let test = source.print().share()

    test.sink { value in
        print("Go")
    }.store(in: &cancellables)

    test.sink { value in
        print("no go ?")
    }.store(in: &cancellables)

    _ = [1,2,3].map { source.send($0) }
```

```
request unlimited
receive value: (1)
Go
no go ?
receive value: (2)
Go
no go ?
receive value: (3)
Go
no go ?
receive cancel
```

Comment: I tried adding a delay so the second subscriber has time to subscribe, but the last event is never received, can you check this out? https://gist.github.com/ivangodfather/53f0c521113b06398e175b3208b549bf

Comment: can you check this out?

Comment: It is a different issue about queues synchronization. Try to use `DispatchQueue.main` (if you have it live after schedule).